# Trigger to open fullscreen dialog works from outside the component, how can close the dialog when opened

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, material-ui

I have passed a state as a prop from a functional component to a fullscreen dialog component, how can I trigger `onClose` or `onClick` to close after the dialog is displayed

```
const [openLetterOnlyDialog, SetOpenLetterOnlyDialog] = React.useState(false);
<LetterOnlyDialog open={openLetterOnlyDialog}/>


 **Dialog component to be opened**
 export default function LettersOnly(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog fullScreen open={props.open} onClose={handleClose} TransitionComponent={Transition}>
            </Dialog>
```

Comment: hi Jee Mok, could you please suggest a possible solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your example, add this function in your component where you are declaring the `LettersOnly` dialog. Pass it the same way you are passing the `open` prop. It will handle the close event of your dialog.

```
 function handleClose() {
     SetOpenLetterOnlyDialog(false);
 }
```

Then the components would look more or less like this:

```
<LetterOnlyDialog open={openLetterOnlyDialog} close={handleClose} />

<Dialog 
    fullScreen 
    open={props.open} 
    onClose={props.close} 
    TransitionComponent={Transition}
></Dialog>
```

Comment: @easyadin, please do not forget to accept the answer